# Read specific hex data in CSV file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've looked through the posts on StackOverflow and can't seem to find the answer I am looking for. I have a large CSV file (450 MB) with hex data that looks like this:

```
63C000CF,6000002F,603000AF,6000C06F,617300EF,6C7C001F,6000009F,0%,63C000CF...
```

That is a very truncated example, but basically I have approximately 78 different hex values separated by commas, then there will be the '0%', then 78 more hex values. This will continue for a very long time. I've been using textscan like this:

```
data = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', '%');
data = textscan(data{1}{1}, '%s', 'delimiter', ',');
data = data{1};

count = size(data);

outstring = ['%', sprintf('\n')];
for idx = 1:count(1)           
    string = data{idx};
    stringSize = size(string);
    if stringSize(2) > 1
        outstring = [outstring, string, sprintf('\n')];
    end
end
fprintf(output_fid, '%s', outstring)
```

This allowed me to format the csv file in a way to which I could use fgetl() to analyze whether or not I was looking at the data I needed. Because the data repeats itself, I can use fseek() to jump to the next occurrence before calling fgetl() again.

What I need is a way to skip to the ending. I want to just be able to use something like fgetl() but have it only return the first hex value it encounters. I will know how many bytes to shift through the file. Then I need to make sure I can read other hex values. Is what I'm asking possible? My code using textscan above takes far too long on a csv file that is 90 MB let alone 450 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer obtained from user Cedric Wannaz on the [Mathworks MATLAB Central Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/132394-read-specific-hex-data-in-csv-file) page.

NEW solution

Here is a more efficient solution; I am using a 122MB file, so you have an idea about the timing

```
% One line for reading the whole file. To perform once only.
 tic ;
 content = fileread( 'adam_1.txt' ) ;
 fprintf( 'Time for reading the file    : %.2fs\n', toc ) ;
 % One line for defining an extraction function. To perform once only.
 extract = @(label) content(bsxfun( @plus, ...
                                    strfind( content, [label,','] ).' - 6, ...
                                    0 : 5 )) ;
 % Then it is one call per label to extract data.
 tic ;
 data = extract( 'CF' ) ;
 fprintf( 'Time for extracting one label: %.2fs\n', toc ) ;
```

Running this, I obtain

> Time for reading the file    : 0.52s
>
> Time for extracting one label: 0.62s

FORMER solution

Would the following work for you?

```
 % Read file content. To do once only.
 content = fileread( 'myFile.txt' ) ;
 % Define regexp-based extraction function. To do once only.
 getByLabel = @(label) regexp( content, sprintf( '\\w{6}(?=%s)', label ), ...
                               'match' ) ;
 % Get all entries for e.g. label 'CF'.
 entries_CF = getByLabel( 'CF' ) ;
 % Get all entries for e.g. label '6F'.
 entries_6F = getByLabel( '6F' ) ;
```

I am not completely clear on what you need to achieve ultimately; if I had to design a GUI where users can choose a label and get corresponding data, I would process the data much further during the init phase, e.g. by grouping them by label in a cell array. Regexp is not the most efficient approach in this case I guess, but the principle would be..

```
 labels  = {'CF', '6F', 'AF', ..} ;
 nLabels = numel( labels ) ;
 data    = cell{ 1, nLabels ) ;
 for lId = 1 : nLabels
    data{lId} = getByLabel( labels{lId} ) ;
 end
```

and then when a user selects 'CF' ..

```
 lId = strcmpi( label, labels ) ;
 dataForThisLabel = data{lId} ;
```